# How to sign java applet with X.509 certificates from Comodo

Tags: x509, jarsigner, signed-applet

I am a newbie to java security and know pretty much nothing about it. I have an existing jar that was given to me couple of years which was digitally signed. However, that signature is now expired and I need to sign it again. The client has bought an X.509 certificate from Comodo and Comodo gave him the following 4 files.
1) AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
2) COMODOCodeSigningCA2.crt
3) UTNAddTrustObject_CA.crt
4) "application_specific_key".crt

I would like to know what the next steps are in order to sign the jar file I have. I have tried doing the following things but I keep getting an error when I use jarsigner to sign the applet jar

1) keytool -import -alias AddTrustExternalCARoot -keystore altis.keystore -file AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
2) keytool -import -alias COMODOCodeSigningCA2 -keystore altis.keystore -file COMODOCodeSigningCA2.crt
3)keytool -import -alias UTNAddTrustObject_CA -keystore altis.keystore -file UTNAddTrustObject_CA.crt
4)keytool -import -alias "application_specific_alias" -keystore altis.keystore -file "application_specific_alias".crt
5) jarsigner "application_jar_file" "application_specific_alias"
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: "application_specific_alias".  "application_specific_alias" must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the certificate along with the private key in a PKCS12 format.

To get this file you need to follow the link that COMODO provided via e-mail using the SAME COMPUTER and the SAME BROWSER that you used to place the order in the first place.

The certificate will be installed using your browser and you'll be able to export it in the PKCS12 format.

To export the certificate COMODO provides the following guides:

Internet Explorer / Chrome browsers:

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/71/0/how-do-i-backup-my-digital-id-certificate-windows-ie

After you have exported the certificate along with the private key in the PKCS12 format you should sign the JAVA applet using the following guide:

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/531/0/signing-jar-files

If your .jar file already have a certificate, you can open it in a compression utility and remove the content from the META-INF folder. Then you can sign the applet.